# Cygwin rsync stop working

Tags: cygwin, rsync

Im using cygwin rsync for backuping data between local drives or remote server. Everything worked fine (I did some backups few days ago) till this day when I wanted backup some directories. Any rsync call ends with following error now:

```
$ rsync -avvv aa/ bb
rsync: pipe: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(122) [sender=3.1.1]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=14, file=pipe.c, line=122): about to call exit(14)
```

Any idea where could be problem?

Im running Cygwin on Windows 8.1.

Thanks

R.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted - rsync has been blocked on firewall.

R.